# decoding a base64 encoded image into the orignal image in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, base64, pymysql

I Pulled a base64 encoded image string from a remote db and tried decoding it using base64.decode() but the output image is a corrupt one (image size is just a few Bytes or even 0 bytes)
The code is:

```
import pymssql
import base64
import os

con=pymssql.connect(user='**',
                    password='**',
                    database='**',
                    host='**')

cur=con.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT PHOTOGRAPH_IMG FROM IHHL_DETAIL_IMG WHERE APPLICATION_ID='**';")
result=cur.fetchall()  #tried fetchone() too
result=list(result)    #to save the tuple returned as a list
print result[0]        

cur.close()
con.close()

#I've tried various formats to decode, none work 
#fh=open("img.jpeg","wb")
#fh.write(result[0].decode('base64'))
with open("imageToSave.png", "wb") as fh:
fh.write(base64.decode(result[0]))
fh.close()
```

Comment: Just add the content as a single line, indented by 4 spaces.  You might want to post an actual question now, by the way, to avoid being downvoted or closed.

Comment: I tried that, turns out the character limit per question is 30000 characters, my binary file has more characters, what do I do now?

Comment: Posting even 10% that much data into a single question is, in my opinion, way too much.  We probably don't need your exact binary data to help you.

Comment: Okay so I'll just edit this question and post my code along with the issue?

Comment: Please just post your question.  SO is mainly geared towards general solutions, rather than an answer using your specific data.

Comment: You guys give more advice than actually solving a problem. Everybody needs to start somewhere right? Guess you weren't born knowing all this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Just add it as "Code"

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```